# Regex to change \ by /

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like the following:

`str_1 = 'my idea\goal is to change \\"this\\"'`

I want to change tha backslash between idea and goal so that it becomes `idea/goal` but without changing the backslash for the double quotes `\\"this\\"`.

I have tried with the following regex:

`str_2 = re.sub(r'([\w]*)\\([\w]*)',r"\1/\2",str_1)`

However, this changes all the backslashes. Can anybody help me? Many thanks in advance

Comment: change only backslashes not followed by quotes? `re.sub(r'\\([^"])',r'/\1',str_1))`

Comment: you whant to get `my idea/goal is to change /\"this/\"` or `my idea/goal is to change \\"this\\"` ?

Comment: Note, by the way, that the backslash between the "a" and the "g" in the literal bound to  `str1` should really be doubled, although your code works as intended since there is currently no defined `\g` string escape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `(\\)(?!")` which indicates backslashes that are not followed by double quotes

```
str_1 = 'my idea\goal is to change \\"this\\"'
str_2 = re.sub(r'(\\)(?!")',r"/",str_1)
```

output:

```
str_1: my idea\goal is to change \"this\"
str_2: my idea/goal is to change \"this\"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would replace backslash by slash only if at end of string or not followed by quote:

```
re.sub(r'\\([^"]|$)',r'/\1',str_1)
```

This captures the backslash + following character (or end of line) and replaces by slash+this character. Result is:

```
my idea/goal is to change \"this\"
```

note that using raw prefix is better to avoid that `\<letter>` is interpreted by Python. In your example it works because `\g` doesn't mean anything but with `\n` it will fail unless backslashes are doubled or `r` prefix is before the string (in which case only one backslash is needed everywhere)

```
str_1 = r'my idea\goal is to change \"this\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuming your own initial idea ( `re.sub(r'([\w]*)\\([\w]*)',r"\1/\2",str_1)` ), which obviously wants to only replace between 2 words - simply fix it like this:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)\\(\w+)', r"\1/\2", str_1)
```

( `+` instead of `*` wants at least one char;  `[]` are not necessary with one item (`\w`) only )

Answer (score -2):

Since you only want to replace the first slash, the simplest solution would be

```
str_2 = str_1.replace("\\", "/", 1)
```

Using the `re` module when it's unnecessary is a frequent cause of problems for those new to Python.

Comment: Except when you are tying to find out how regular expressions in Python behave for certain tasks.

Comment: Learning exercises are always legitimate. @mjrezaee's answer using the "negative lookahead assertion" that doesn't consume any characters as matched is hard to beat.

Comment: Despite the downvotes I am leaving this answer visible, since the question did not specifically ask for a regex-based solution, and beginners are often unaware of much simpler alternatives that should almost always be preferred.